Problem with visual duplication issues in the IDE's terminal
I am using this new AI IDE called Cursor, where I starting getting these weird visual glitch, where the content gets shown again and again, when I adject the high of the terminal.
It ends up looking like this (*edited):
PS C:\\...hidden>

PS C:\\...hidden>

PS C:\\...hidden>
PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd

PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd

PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd

PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd
PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd

PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd
PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd asda

PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd asda

PS C:\\...hidden> asdasd asda

I did turn off GPU Acceleration, which did nothing. I would love to hear if someone had this, and knows how to fix it.
GPU Acceleration

https://github.com/getcursor/cursor/issues is where you could report problems with their tool.
